# Override instance function in test file

Tags: lua, overriding

I am trying to override a function from a class in Lua, but it is not working as I expected. This is how my class file looks like:

car.lua

```
function car.tesla:start_car()
    -- do some stuff
    result = self.crank()
    -- do other stuff
end

function car.tesla.crank()
    -- calculate some_boolean
    return some_boolean
end
```

In my test file I want to mock the output of crank() function for a specific instance

in my test_car.lua file

```
local test_car = car_module.car:new("tesla")

test_car.crank = function() return true end

test_car.start()
assertEquals(test_car.is_started, true)
```

I also tried writing another function and doing the assignation but it didn't work either:

```
function mock_crank()
    return true
end

test_car.crank = mock_crank
```

When added debugging print statements, I see that the original function is being invoked instead of the overriding i am doing in the test file. What I am doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to show us where `car.tesla.crank()` is called. I highly suspect that it's called as `car.tesla.crank()` rather than `self:crank()` or the like since it appears to be intended as "static" (i.e. no `:` was used in it's def.)

Comment: Lua does not have classes per se, rather many modules attempt to mimic class-like behavior. You probably need to show your implementation of classes for us to get the full picture of what could be going wrong.